# What happens internally when passing a pointer by value?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Suppose I have a following linked list structure:

```
struct linked_list
{
    struct linked_list *next;
    int data;
};
typedef struct linked_list node;
```

And the following function to print the linked list:

```
void print(node *ptr)
{
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ->",ptr->data);
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
}
```

Now in the `main()` function when I write this:

```
print(head); // Assume head is the pointer pointing to the head of the list
```

This is essentially call-by-value. Because `ptr` in `print` will receive a copy of `head`. And we can't modify `head` from the `print()` function because its call-by-value.

But my doubt is, since `ptr` receives a copy of `head` but it's able to print the value of linked list. So does that means the `print()` function receives whole copy of linked list? If it does not receives the whole copy of linked list how its able to print the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print` receives a copy of the *address* of head, which means that the data representing `head` isn't copied: the function is using the actual head and hence the actual linked list, not a copy.

The implications are that you **can** change `head`, e.g. `head->data`, and you can modify the rest of the linked list. The only thing that you can't do is change *which* node your passed-in pointer points to, i.e. you can't do `head = NULL` in `print` and expect that to be reflected outside `print`.

So, any of the following changes are all reflected outside the function:

```
// pick one:
ptr->data = 20;
ptr->next = NULL;
ptr->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
ptr->next->data = 20;
// etc.
```

The following **aren't**:

```
ptr = NULL;
ptr = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

Comment: Thanks I got it. I was thinking in wrong direction. I totally suck when am confused at such minute concepts.

Answer (score 4):

Your function receives a copy of the pointer. The copy of the pointer points to the same place as the original pointer.

A pointer is like an address. Here's an analogy. Imagine writing your address down on a piece of paper. When you want to give it to a friend you copy the address: that is, you write the same address on a new piece of paper and give that paper to your friend. But if they go to the address written on their copy, they'll go to the exactly same place as if they had gone to the address on the original piece of paper.

Comment: But if the copy of the pointer points to the same place as original pointer why can't we modify the linked list inside print function without using double pointers? Suppose am modifying inside print function, then on what data the modification is taking place?

Comment: @AndroidDecoded: There's two situations. If your friend changes the pointer - i.e. they write on the paper and change the address. Say they change a 4 to a 5, that doesn't actually change your house's physical address, it just means that their piece of paper no longer points to your house. Maybe it points to a different house or no house at all. It does not change the original copy - you can still use your piece of paper to find your house. It only changes their copy. Now imagine a slightly different situation: they follow the pointer, go to your house and smash it up. That affects everyone.

Comment: modifying inside the function, the modifications are happening to the same data/same list as outside the function. only the _address_ is pass-by-value, so you'll only need double-pointers when you need to change e.g. what `head` points to. The rest of the list can be freely modified, including the `data` element

Comment: So here I can't modify the head pointer, but I can modify the other pointers? For eg: ptr->next->data=20;

Then this changes will reflect in main() function also?

Comment: Oh got it.. I was thinking something else. Thanks @pb2q

Comment: yes. `ptr->data=20` is reflected in main, so is `ptr->next = NULL`, `ptr->next->data=20`, etc. the only thing that **isn't** reflected is, e.g. `ptr=NULL` or `ptr = malloc(sizeod(node))`, assigning it to a new node

Comment: @pb2q One more thing. You said malloc will not be reflected. But since ptr points to same list. and we do ptr->next= malloc(sizeof(node)) then it should also be reflected?

Comment: yes you **can** change what next points to. only the pointer to the head is a copy and can't be changed